# Excel VBA: Call Sub Procedure from function

Tags: vba, excel

My code is retrieving an HTML page as an object, given a certain parameter:

```
Public Sub MyPage(myparam)
Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument

Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument

With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.example.com" & myparam, False
    .send
    oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

End Sub
```

I'm defining functions that will use the same object, therefore, I want to minimize the number of connections. So I want to define a function like:

```
Function myFunction(myparam As String)

Call MyPage(myparam)

'code here

End Function
```

But this isn't working. When I type =myFunction into a cell, I get the #VALUE! error.

If I just type the code of the sub procedure inside the function, it works, something like:

```
Function myFunction(myparam As String)

Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument

Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument

With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.example.com" & myparam, False
    .send
    oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

    'code here

End Function
```

But, as mentioned above, this will require the same connection and object for different functions.

How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: The two methods use the same quantity of resources. I don't see differences.

Comment: have you tried with `oHtml` used as `public variable`?

Comment: @KazJaw Bingo, that's it, so simple!

Comment: @jacouh the intention is precisely to use the less resouces possible, do you know if you can establish a single connection/object to be used by several functions better than this one?

Comment: KazJaw has the solution, create once oHtml object... More Function myFunction(myparam As String)

Call MyPage(myparam)

'code here

End Function works for me on Excel 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer:

Use your `oHtml variable` as `Public variable`.